# How does R remember which values were indexed?

Tags: r, indexing

Code:

```
x <- c(1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 5)   
x[x < 3] <- x[x <  3]  *  100  
x
```

Output:

```
[1]  100  100    3  200    3    5
```

I expected to get the output “`[1] 100 100 200`”. How does R remember the indexes where `x < 3?` Because when running `x[x < 3]`, you get the output “`1,1,2`” (and the indexes of those numbers are `1,2,4)`.

Hence, R remember the values where `x < 3`, and manipulates those values. But how does R know the indexes of those values?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment

Comment: `(x[x < 3] <- x[x<3]  *  100)` gives `[1] 100 100 200`, you can assign the result of that to another object like `x2`

Comment: @Cath It is good if you pass you comment as an answer.

Comment: you can extend it to a function that can work for any values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the result of your call you need to assign it to a new variable:

```
x2 <- (x[x < 3] <- x[x<3] * 100) 
x2
#[1] 100 100 200
```

Note that `x` will still be changed (as a result of your assignment `x[x < 3] <- x[x<3] * 100`).
If that is not desired, you can simply do:

```
x2 <- x[x<3]*100
x2
#[1] 100 100 200
x
#[1] 1 1 3 2 3 5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at what is x < 3 you'll find it yields

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

so `x[x<3] <- x[x <  3]  *  100`  means multiply by 100 the first, second and fourth value of x (`x[x <  3]*100`)  and replace  the first, second and fourth value of x by these new values (`x[x<3] <-`).

Answer (score 1):

It's not remembering the locations of the `x < 3` values.  The left-hand side of your equation is explicitly the locations of the `x < 3` values.

So the thing on the right might be `(100, 100, 200)`, but the thing on the left is *the placeholders at places 1, 2 and 4*.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you ask R to go to `x` and multiple each value less than `3` by `100` that is in this code `x[x < 3]*100`. R, in this case, looks for the place of your element. That is, the code goes to `x` values and takes them one by one. The one that obeys the condition is then multiplied by `100`. Then, the code returns you all the values of `x`. The correct way is to assign a name to your specific values as @Cath answer.

In addition, it is a good idea to write a general function for your convenience. Here is a function.

```
myfun <- function(x, n){

res <- lapply(x, function(i) (if (i < n) {i *100}else{0}))
res
}
```

or simply use the comment of @Cath.

```
myfun <- function(x, n){

res <- x[x < n]*100
res
}

myfun(x, 3)

x <- list(1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 5)  
n=3
```

Then,

```
 > myfun(x, 3)
[[1]]
[1] 100

[[2]]
[1] 100

[[3]]
[1] 0

[[4]]
[1] 200

[[5]]
[1] 0

[[6]]
[1] 0
```

Comment: why put `x` as list and use `lapply` when you can vectorise it? you can just do `myfun <- function(x, n) x[x<n]*100`

Comment: @Cath, thanks a lot. I like to use `lapply` since sometimes we have a large list. I mean I like the output of `lapply`.

Comment: You didn't really answer a question about the inner workings of R.  And the function does't do what the question is asking.

Comment: I think you also did not answer the question. The only answer that answers the question is the answer that shows the `TRUE` and `False`.

Comment: @lebelinoz, with full respect to you. I told the OP, the wrong in the code and why the output is not as expected. I included a function for OP convenience.